# MomentJs : How to get start of the same week last year?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need function for getting the start of the same week last year.

For example I have date : 2016-01-10 and it's the first date of the 3d week in 2016, so I need the first day of the 3d week of 2015 and it would be 2015-01-11

(I always need the first day and let's consider that I allways get the first dat of week as param for my function).

I have created such function:

```
var getTheSameWeekLastYear = function (date) {
    var date = moment(date).startOf("week"),
        weekNo = date.week();
    // move a year ago and set the same week
    return date.add(-1, "y").week(weekNo).startOf("week");
}
```

And it works fine until I got week wich starts in last year and end this year. For example, week#1 2016 - starts 2015-12-27 and ends 2016-01-02.

I this case I am getting thee same week for a year before last year - 2013-12-29.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/3817/)

What is the best way to solve this problem?
Probably momentjs has any built in function for my task?

Comment: Some years have only 52 weeks, and others have 53 or even 54 weeks. You will need to manually check and calculate situations for 1st, 52nd, 53rd and 54th weeks, because they can belong into previous or next year.

Comment: Examples: 1st week of 2015 starts 2014-12-29 and 2014 have only 52 weeks. But 2015 have 53 weeks and first week of 2016 starts 2016-01-04 so you must decide if 1st week of 2016 (2016-01-04) should output 1st week on 2015 (2014-12-29) or 2nd week (2015-01-05). And if 53rd week of 2015 (2015-12-28) should output 52nd week of 2014 (2014-12-22) or 1st week of 2015 (2014-12-29)...

Comment: @RadekPech great question, thanks. I haven't thougth about it bfore.
if have 53 weeks this year and 52 last year, it should move to the first week of this year.